# Catch HTTP POST from Webhook in server

Tags: http, http-post, server

I am trying to catch `HTTP POST` which webhook sends. 
I made a test server in Azure and its URL is `http://whtestingserver.cloudapp.net`.

Here is what I am confused about.
1. When I set up the webhook, it asked me to enter URL. Does this URL means my server URL? Then can I put `http://whtestingserver.cloudapp.net`?

2. How can I grab `HTTP POST` that webhook sends? Do I need to make a webpage to grab it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Webhook is asking for is the full URL that will be called (as HTTP POST request) when it's triggered. What will you do when someone calls your script that activates on provided URL is your thing. There's not enough details (what's on the server?, what webserver is it?, how does that specific technology/framework routes the incoming requests?). Base line is - webhook is just another HTTP request (as if the user would submit a form from browser over POST).

In PHP you could have PHP script called "webhook.php" that would have URL like http://whtestingserver.cloudapp.net/webhook.php and once the hook is "triggered" it'll send HTTP POST request to http://whtestingserver.cloudapp.net/webhook.php and then your script do it's job...

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: so I need to make a webpage and host it on server?